# Issue with scope.$eval in a third party directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I am using a selectionModel(selection-model.js) directive in my application. I am passing some values to directive using attribute in my element.

In the directive link function, value is being read like =

```
var smMode = scope.$eval(attrs.selectionModelMode) || defaultMode
```

Earlier, the directive was working fine but suddenly it is not working anymore. when i investigated and found `scope.$eval(attrs.selectionModelMode)` is coming as undefined and it's falling back to defaultMode.

Directive does not have a isolated scope. but it's used with ng-repeat.

When I am adding a property to parent scope as `attrs.selectionModelMode = 'multiple'` and change the directive code to 
`var smMode = scope.$parent.$eval('attrs.selectionModelMode') || defaultMode`
then only it's working.

The problem with this I can not change the directive code. Is there any work around in AngularJS for this?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Could you post your html where you set `selection-model-mode` and maybe a little surrounding code for context?